# Remote debugging - variable does not exist in the current context

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, debugging, .net-core

I'm trying to debug a code using the remote debugger. The application is in .Net Core and is running in Linux. The connection works fine and the breakpoints are hit.

The only issue is that I can't read the variables value (when the BP is hit) and if I add the variable to the Watch List or check the value using the Immediate Window I receive an error because the variable "does not exist in the current context".

I can't find a reference on https://github.com/dotnet/core/issues, I'll open an issue.

### Edit

Of course if I run the project on my computer instead of the remote server all the variables are read without any kind of issue. And of course the remote DLL(s) are compiled in Debug mode.

### Important note

In this specific scenario the DLL is loaded with Reflection. Since I had some issue with breakpoints I set `<DebugType>embedded</DebugType>` and `<DebugSymbols>true</DebugSymbols>` (in .csproject file) to include all the symbols to the .dll.

Opened issue on Git: https://github.com/dotnet/core/issues/1928

Comment: Is it possible that you are running a "Release" version remotely, and a debug version locally? The release version may optimize away variables so that they won't exist.

Comment: Nope, i compiled in Debug mode only and uploaded it to the server. I'm 100% sure that the remote file is in Debug mode.
To be sure that all the symbols are loaded I also set the ```<DebugType>embedded</DebugType>``` into the .csproj file so all the symbols are included into the .dll